# Getting a variable from fragment to recyclerview Adapter and listening its value in adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, click, fragment, onclicklistener

There is a need of sorting record in recycler view adapter, based on the platform chosen from buttons in fragment.
I can't use interface as I already used in Adapter to listen in fragment. if I use interface now it will cause cyclic redundancy.
Can you please let me know the procedure for this. Thanks!

- I'm sorry I'm only allowed to upload image links, Thank you very much for all your support and looking forward for the solution!!

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: Need more information for the question. this is understandable for you it's ok but for others, it does not give any idea what's going wrong here!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [1- UI]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy7ES.png][1]

  [2- Home Fragment]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJVL4.png][1]

  [3- Book Adapter-1]: [`https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4dxZ.png`][1]

  [4- Books Adapter-2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJZzI.png

  [5- Gradle]: https: //i.stack.imgur.com/9Q1Xo.png

Answer (score -1):

you get a variable from the fragment using intent, later you pass that variable to the recycler view through the adapter (create a method to update a variable inside the adapter class) and I'll say to update the adapter everytime your fragment variable changes.

if you provide a screenshot of your code I can give a better answer, it depends how you implemented it.

Comment: `you get a variable from the fragment using intent` OP hasn't mentioned intents anywhere and typically activities work with intents, not fragments ?

Comment: [1- UI]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy7ES.png][1]

  [2- Home Fragment]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJVL4.png][1]

  [3- Book Adapter-1]: [`https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4dxZ.png`][1]

  [4- Books Adapter-2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJZzI.png

  [5- Gradle]: https: //i.stack.imgur.com/9Q1Xo.png

Comment: i check the screenshots, you are passing many values to the adapter, and later you are just displaying the values depending on the user selection. If you want to sort by user selection I'll check what the user chooose before passing the list to the adapter, later you sort the list and finally pass the values to the adapter. I'll remove the "if" in the onBindViewHolder. If you still need help send me a message.

Comment: Thank you Elvishrdz for your valuable suggestion, here I have to get all the selected values from different platform so I can sort it in fragment, I have to sort it in Adapter and finally have to send back the selected values from the three platforms to the fragment for further processing.